# Removing text after 2nd space in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro to export a column of names (column A) into a .csv

Examples,

1. MARY JANE
2. THOMAS LEE
3. RYAN CHRISTOPHER SMITH

What I want to do is to only take the first 2 parts of the name, since some names have more than 3 parts, so that it ends up like this

1. MARY JANE
2. THOMAS LEE
3. RYAN CHRISTOPHER

I am able to do it with a normal cell function, however I can't seem to make it work with VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Instr` to locate a character in a string, from a specified starting point.  So use it twice, 2nd time starting after the first found position

```
Function TwoWords(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    ' remove any multiple or leading /trailing spaces
    str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(str)

    ' locate 2nd space if it exists
    i = InStr(str, " ")
    If i > 0 Then
        i = InStr(i + 1, str, " ")
        If i > 0 Then
            str = Left$(str, i - 1)
        End If
    End If

    TwoWords = str
End Function

Sub Demo()
    Dim str As String
    ' For Demo
    str = TwoWords("RYAN CHRISTOPHER SMITH")
    Debug.Print str

    str = TwoWords("THOMAS LEE")
    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

View the results of `Demo` in the Immediate Window